# Get broken hard (or soft) constraints

Tags: drools, drools-planner

Like the question says. After a

```
solver.solve();
```

I want to see specific rules (with values) that were violated. How can I get them from the solution?

Comment: Hi. did you solved your problem?

Comment: I havent tried it **yet** as I am tied up. But I would personally vouch for using soft constraints (with a large negative score) for all non-impossible but highly undesirable states and using planning entity difficulty to tell Drools to assign tougher-to-assign entities. My program needs to handle "rogue" rules from many users, so removing hard constraints helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples already do this, take a look at this method:

```
org.drools.planner.examples.common.business.SolutionBusiness#getScoreDetailList()
```

But it's not standardized yet, see [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3328).

Comment: I modified this method to my code, but the flow always goes to `if (workingMemory == null) { return Collections.emptyList(); }`. What can be reasons for this? It is strange, because in documentation is said that DroolsScoreDirector.getWorkingMemory() never returns null, but it does.

Comment: @akapelko in the manual, look for guiScoreDirector. My guess is you're not using the Solver.getScoreDirectorFactory() to create a ScoreDirector for you. Or that you haven't called ScoreDirector.resetSolution() to tell it about your solution.